# Access variable outside of axios promise method.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to push some data into a variable that is held outside of a axios promise method. But it does not allow me to do so.

```
export default function () {

  let storage = []

  axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/content')
      .then(res => {
        let posts = res.data.map(obj => obj);
        storage.push({posts});
      })
    return storage
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this. Also in terms of the long term. What is the best way to place api data into a reducer for react/redux. I am learning redux and trying to figure out how to do this the best way. It seems my above method is not ideal?
Thanks.

Comment: `return storage` in the `.then` callback?

Comment: `it does not allow me to do so` what does that mean?

Comment: Ah, so to be specific, when I return this function. I receive a empty list, the axios function does not push anything to the array.

Comment: That's because you're returning storage before the request is actually done Read up on how async works in javascript. Return storage after you push posts in it, then it should work.